# Change Text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that is pulling in news from Yahoo on a certain subject. It renders the title of the news feed like this:

```
<div class="header-title">subject - Yahoo! News Search Results</div>
```

I would like to change this to read differently. Since this is inserted via JS I thought I could change this with jQuery.

I attempted this:

```
$('.header-title').text('Subject News');
```

that did not work, I then attempted this:

```
$('.header-title').empty();
$('.header-title').text('Subject News');
```

that also did not work.

Both of the above methods look as if they had no effect on the text.

I am not sure what to do to remove the old text and replace with my text.

Note: All of my code is inside jQuery's Document Ready IE:

```
$(function(){ 
   //Code Here 
});
```

Comment: is other script completely creating the complete content of the widget including title? If so it could be asynchronous and not be built when DOM is ready

Comment: Please create a jsBin demo with your issue! :)

Comment: For me (Firefox 16.0), your example works, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZ5XH/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This solution assumes you have no access to the other script that creates the feed widget**

WIthout knowing more about other script it sounds like it is asynchronous, and creates the title elements also. You could have a timed interval loop that checks for the element to exist and once it exists do the update:

```
function changeYahooTitle(){
     var $yhooTitle=$('.header-title');
    if($yhooTitle.length){
        $yhooTitle.text('My New Title');
    }else{
        /* doesn't exist so check again in 1/10th second, will loop recursively until found*/
        setTimeout(changeYahooTitle, 100);
    }
}
```

Then on page load:

```
$(function(){
  changeYahooTitle()

})
```

If you do have access to the other script it can be modified to accommodate your needs, or you can still use this solution

Comment: Your solution was able to solve my issue. I do have access to the original script, however, I am using your solution as I do not want to edit the original script. A quick `FOUC` does happen but I modified your answer to prevent this: ` $yhooTitle.text('My New Title').css('display', 'block');` (`.header-title` is set to `display:none;`) Thanks!

Comment: don't want this running indefintiely on pages the widget will never exist... might add a time elapsed component and stop it if overdue. Or only run it if a specific parent for feed exists

Comment: Not sure I follow, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: simple.. loop runs until element found... if never found will run for as long as user has page open. Can use `var now=Date.now()` and get DATE inside loop and check difference, or only run this code using some other part of page that tells you the widget has to exist

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to put your code in [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
    $(".header-title").text("Subject News");
});
```

Otherwise the code should work fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my post, but all of my code is contained within DOM Ready.

Comment: @JFK - Maybe it is the other script conflicting?

Comment: @Lynda It might happen that you have errors in JavaScript *before* this line. Check it using JavaScript console.

Comment: Here is how to open the browser console in different browsers in case you need it: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: @Lynda if you can share a link, we could help you to spot it (or create a sample page)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `empty()` and `text()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header-title").html("Subject News");
});
```

Comment: When I try that it is still the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening:

1. First you're setting the text: `$('.header-title').text('Subject News');`
2. THEN ... after the data finishes the load of the Yahoo or whatever content your text gets replaced actually with the new fetched data

   **Change the text inside the load callback (after data is loaded) and it will work.**

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work because you call the function before the  element is created. If you put your function inside `<script>` tag after the `<div>` element it should work

Comment: script tag after element has no benefits over calling code in `ready` handler. `ready` doesn't fire until all html is loaded

Comment: @charlietfl can you proove this statement?

Comment: @roXon I didn't state that it doesn't work and am completely aware that `ready` isn't needed if code is placed after elemtns... however OP has stated they are using `ready` so changing code placement won't change situation. Please reread my statement

Comment: It's not necessarily true. DOM might be rendered but the div element is not in the dom if it is added with js after the rendering dom. Coming back to the original question the issue is that she calls her functions before the function which creates the div element and not after.

Comment: @jonasnas  absolutely correct ...   so there is no element to place the script tag after if it is a third party script...  or as my answer suggests... is most likely created in asynchronous function. Situation is same.. if not therein `ready` won't be there when you place script tag near their script either